# what is the name of this operation: $x^T\otimes B$

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

So the question is simple: how the following operation is commonly called?

$x^T\otimes B$, each element of matrix B is multiplied by the array $x^T$, so the result is a matrix. I'm not even sure if I used the correct symbol.

Comment: Since a matrix already has two positional indices, it would seem (if $x$ is a vector) that you are building something that needs three positional indices; I don't see how the result is a matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), the finite-dimensional version of the [tensor product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Tensor_product_of_linear_maps).

Comment: That's it! perfect!